# ActiveRecord and sqlite3 : find does not accept any condition?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sqlite, find

I have a problem I can't figure out here. I'm writing a ruby script that deals with an sqllite database.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sqlite3'
require 'active_record'


ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => "sqlite3",
    :database  => "../database/my.db"
)

class KeyWord < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "keywords"
end

# THIS STATEMENT WORKS (finds the first record, returns "ruby") :    
KeyWord.find(1).keyval


# THOSE STATEMENTS RETURN NO RESULT :      
KeyWord.find(:all, :conditions => {:keyval => "ruby"})

KeyWord.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE keyval='ruby'")

KeyWord.find_by_keyval("ruby")
```

This is how the table was created :

```
create_table :keywords do |table|
    table.column :keyval, :text
end
```

Does anyone know where this could come from ?

Thanks,

R.

Comment: Can you include the output of your first statement: `p KeyWord.find(1).keyval`? I think the issue probably has to do with how the value is stored in the DB.

Comment: `> p KeyWord.find(1).keyval` gives "ruby" (with the quotes. They don't appear if I use puts. Should they not be there ?)

Comment: They should be there with p. I was wondering if your text column had any space padding. Can you find the KeyWord using `KeyWord.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE keyval LIKE '%ruby%'")`?

Comment: No it does not work neither. I start to think that I have a library problem because I have other weird errors that no one complains about on the web.. Here I use `:text`, but if I use `:string` I can't insert values properly..

Comment: It sounds like you might need to re-install sqlite3 and ensure that it is properly setup and working via a console first.

Comment: You should try the database with sqlite3 command, if it works as expected then try rebuilding the gem.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues here.

- I'm not sure why you're manually setting your table name. 
  ActiveRecord assumes that your model name is camelCased. So...  AR
  would, by default, search for a table called key_words.  Why not just
  go with that?
- Pay attention to which version of active record you are
  using. Passing in conditions is deprecated.  You should be using the
  `.where` syntax.  So...  you would need to do `KeyWord.where(:keyval
  => 'ruby').first` or end in `.all` for a collection of results.
- If you are just fooling around, you can use sqlite3 in memory.
  `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( adapter: 'sqlite3',
  database: ":memory:")`
- Also don't forget to define your schema!

Here is full code w/ more modern syntax.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sqlite3'
require 'active_record'


ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ":memory:" )

ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = false
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2) do
  create_table :key_words do |t|
    t.text   :keyval
  end
end

class KeyWord < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Keyword.create!(:keyval => 'ruby')

# THESE STATEMENTS WORK:
KeyWord.find(1).keyval
KeyWord.where(:keyval => 'ruby').first 
KeyWord.where(:keyval => 'ruby').all
KeyWord.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM key_words WHERE keyval='ruby'")
KeyWord.find_by_keyval("ruby")
```